# Azure Web-App Maximum Execution Time Issue

Tags: python, django, azure

I am developing a python django app for my project. Due the nature of one of my apps, I need to run a certain script for a long period of time (maybe several hours).

Obviously everything is fine in my local environment. However, when I publish that app to the azure, the app crashes after a period of time due to max. execution time (It is not giving some error related to max. execution instead it throws an internal server error)

At this point I have 2 questions:

- Is it possible to increase max. execution time for a python web-app in azure? If yes, how can I do that?
- Should I be using some other azure service rather than a web-app for such an operation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to leverage [WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) to run your certain scripts or programs for on demand, continuously, or on a schedule tasks on background.

And at the same time, as web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time

by default. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable **Always On** to keep the app loaded all the time. Especially if you need to run continuous or a long time job or task, you should enable **Always On**.
You can modify this setting in manage portal, refer to [Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/) for details.